# Add a button (spinner) in this code

Tags: java, android

I have this code. I define a new class "diagrama" extends View in which i draw somethings.

I want to add a button (specially a spinner button) in the bottom of the screen, but i don't know how.

I'm trying to make a state machine, pressing two "states" and then, link them with a line. I want to appear in each line the input and output with text.

I have tried to make a AlertBuild for select the input and output (it is commented), but i didn't succed. I want to create two spinners buttons for select the input and output.

I'm starting and this app is not fine, but i'm stuck in this and i can't continue.

If someone can help me, i would appreciate.

Thank you.

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Paint.Style;
import android.graphics.Path;
import android.graphics.RectF;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends Activity{


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(new diagrama(this)); //creo el layout "diagrama" desde java y no desde xml

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    public class diagrama extends View{

        //coordenadas x y en el momento en el que tocas la pantalla
        float x=0;
        float y=0;
        float x_origen,y_origen,x_destino,y_destino;

        //coordenadas de los centros de cada círculo
        float   x_S0=160, y_S0=100, 
                x_S1=260, y_S1=200,
                x_S2=160, y_S2=200,
                x_S3=160, y_S3=300,
                x_S4=60,  y_S4=200, 
                radio=20,
                radio_ovalo=100;

        int contador=0, //contador de las 2 bolas pulsadas
                contador_lineas=0, //contador de número de flechas dibujadas
                i=0;

        String accion="accion"; //acción para cuando pulsas un círculo que se coloree en rojo
        String text;    
        Path path= new Path(); //path para crear flechas    


        public diagrama (Context context) {
            super(context);
        }


        //Método para dibujar
        @Override
        protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas){

            //Creamos el pincel con el que vamos a dibujar
            Paint pincel = new Paint();
            pincel.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            pincel.setStrokeWidth(2);
            pincel.setStyle(Style.STROKE);

            //Creamos el camino del ovalo principal
            final RectF ovalo_principal = new RectF();
            ovalo_principal.set(x_S2-radio_ovalo, 
                    y_S2-radio_ovalo, 
                    x_S2+radio_ovalo, 
                    y_S2+radio_ovalo);

            //Creamos el camino del ovalo de la izquierda
            final RectF ovalo_izquierda = new RectF();
            ovalo_izquierda.set(x_S4-((3*radio_ovalo)/2), 
                    y_S4-((3*radio_ovalo)/2), 
                    x_S4+((3*radio_ovalo)/2), 
                    y_S4+((3*radio_ovalo)/2));

            //Creamos el camino del ovalo de la derecha
            final RectF ovalo_derecha = new RectF();
            ovalo_derecha.set(x_S1-((3*radio_ovalo)/2), 
                    y_S1-((3*radio_ovalo)/2), 
                    x_S1+((3*radio_ovalo)/2), 
                    y_S1+((3*radio_ovalo)/2));

            //Creamos el camino del ovalo superior derecha
            final RectF ovalo_superior_derecha = new RectF();
            ovalo_superior_derecha.set(x_S1-radio_ovalo, 
                    y_S1-100-radio_ovalo, 
                    x_S1+radio_ovalo, 
                    y_S1-100+radio_ovalo);

            //Creamos el camino del ovalo superior izquierda
            final RectF ovalo_superior_izquierda = new RectF();
            ovalo_superior_izquierda.set(x_S4-radio_ovalo, 
                    y_S4-100-radio_ovalo, 
                    x_S4+radio_ovalo, 
                    y_S4-100+radio_ovalo);

            //Creamos el camino del ovalo inferior izquierda
            final RectF ovalo_inferior_izquierda = new RectF();
            ovalo_inferior_izquierda.set(x_S4-radio_ovalo, 
                    y_S4+100-radio_ovalo, 
                    x_S4+radio_ovalo, 
                    y_S4+100+radio_ovalo);

            //Creamos el camino del ovalo inferior derecha
            final RectF ovalo_inferior_derecha = new RectF();
            ovalo_inferior_derecha.set(x_S1-radio_ovalo, 
                    y_S1+100-radio_ovalo, 
                    x_S1+radio_ovalo, 
                    y_S1+100+radio_ovalo);

            //Creamos el camino del ovalo pequeño superior
            final RectF ovalo_pequeño_superior = new RectF();
            ovalo_pequeño_superior.set(x_S0-(radio_ovalo/2)+radio, 
                    y_S0+50-(radio_ovalo/2)+radio, 
                    x_S0+(radio_ovalo/2)-radio, 
                    y_S0+50+(radio_ovalo/2)-radio);

            //Creamos el camino del ovalo pequeño inferior
            final RectF ovalo_pequeño_inferior = new RectF();
            ovalo_pequeño_inferior.set(x_S0-(radio_ovalo/2), 
                    y_S0+150-(radio_ovalo/2), 
                    x_S0+(radio_ovalo/2), 
                    y_S0+150+(radio_ovalo/2));

            //Creamos el camino del ovalo pequeño derecha
            final RectF ovalo_pequeño_derecha = new RectF();
            ovalo_pequeño_derecha.set(x_S4+150-(radio_ovalo/2), 
                    y_S4-(radio_ovalo/2), 
                    x_S4+150+(radio_ovalo/2), 
                    y_S4+(radio_ovalo/2));

            //Creamos el camino del ovalo pequeño derecha
            final RectF ovalo_pequeño_izquierda = new RectF();
            ovalo_pequeño_izquierda.set(x_S4+50-(radio_ovalo/2), 
                    y_S4-(radio_ovalo/2), 
                    x_S4+50+(radio_ovalo/2), 
                    y_S4+(radio_ovalo/2));

            //Creamos el camino del ovalo inferior
            final RectF ovalo_inferior = new RectF();
            ovalo_inferior.set(x_S3-((float) Math.sqrt((radio_ovalo*radio_ovalo)+(radio_ovalo*radio_ovalo))), 
                    y_S3-((float)Math.sqrt((radio_ovalo*radio_ovalo)+(radio_ovalo*radio_ovalo))), 
                    x_S3+((float)Math.sqrt((radio_ovalo*radio_ovalo)+(radio_ovalo*radio_ovalo))), 
                    y_S3+((float)Math.sqrt((radio_ovalo*radio_ovalo)+(radio_ovalo*radio_ovalo))));

            //Creamos el camino del ovalo superior
            final RectF ovalo_superior = new RectF();
            ovalo_superior.set(x_S0-((float) Math.sqrt((radio_ovalo*radio_ovalo)+(radio_ovalo*radio_ovalo))), 
                    y_S0-((float)Math.sqrt((radio_ovalo*radio_ovalo)+(radio_ovalo*radio_ovalo))), 
                    x_S0+((float)Math.sqrt((radio_ovalo*radio_ovalo)+(radio_ovalo*radio_ovalo))), 
                    y_S0+((float)Math.sqrt((radio_ovalo*radio_ovalo)+(radio_ovalo*radio_ovalo))));

            //Dibujamos círculos y letras
            canvas.drawCircle(x_S0, y_S0, radio, pincel);
            canvas.drawText("S0",x_S0-5,y_S0+5, pincel);

            canvas.drawCircle(x_S1, y_S1, radio, pincel);
            canvas.drawText("S1",x_S1-5,y_S1+5, pincel);

            canvas.drawCircle(x_S2, y_S2, radio, pincel);
            canvas.drawText("S2",x_S2-5,y_S2+5, pincel);

            canvas.drawCircle(x_S3, y_S3, radio, pincel);
            canvas.drawText("S3",x_S3-5,y_S3+5, pincel);

            canvas.drawCircle(x_S4, y_S4, radio, pincel);
            canvas.drawText("S4",x_S4-5,y_S4+5, pincel);

            //Si se pulsa un círculo, lo pintamos de rojo como si estuviera seleccionado
            if (accion=="S0"){

                pincel.setColor(Color.RED);
                canvas.drawText("S0",x_S0-5,y_S0+5, pincel);
                pincel.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            }

            if (accion=="S1"){

                pincel.setColor(Color.RED);
                canvas.drawText("S1",x_S1-5,y_S1+5, pincel);
                pincel.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            }

            if (accion=="S2"){

                pincel.setColor(Color.RED);
                canvas.drawText("S2",x_S2-5,y_S2+5, pincel);
                pincel.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            }

            if (accion=="S3"){

                pincel.setColor(Color.RED);
                canvas.drawText("S3",x_S3-5,y_S3+5, pincel);
                pincel.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            }

            if (accion=="S4"){

                pincel.setColor(Color.RED);
                canvas.drawText("S4",x_S4-5,y_S4+5, pincel);
                pincel.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            }


            //Para el segundo círculo pulsado
            if (contador==2){



                //              //Mostramos el diálogo de alerta
                //              final CharSequence[] items = {"0 / 0", "0 / 1", "1 / 0", "1 / 1"};
                //              AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
                //              builder.setTitle("Indica combinación de entrada/salida");
                //      
                //              builder.setSingleChoiceItems(items, -1, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                //                  public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
                //                      
                //                      if (item==1){
                //                          text="0 / 0";
                //                          dialog.cancel();
                //                      }
                //
                //                      if (item==2){
                //                          text="0 / 1";
                //                          dialog.cancel();
                //                      }
                //
                //                      if (item==3){
                //                          text="1 / 0";
                //                          dialog.cancel();
                //                      }
                //
                //                      if (item==4){
                //                          text="1 / 1";
                //                          dialog.cancel();
                //                      }
                //                  }
                //
                //              });
                //              
                //              AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
                //              alert.show();


                //Vemos cuál es el segundo círculo pulsado
                if ((x>=x_S0-radio && x<=x_S0+radio) && (y>=y_S0-radio && y<=y_S0+radio)){ //S0

                    x_destino=x_S0; //guardamos las coordenadas del segundo círculo pulsado como destino
                    y_destino=y_S0;


                    if (x_origen==260 && y_origen==200){ //S1

                        path.arcTo(ovalo_principal,-12,-66 ,true);
                        canvas.drawPath(path, pincel);
                        //                          canvas.drawTextOnPath(text, path, 50, 20, pincel);
                    }

                    if (x_origen==60 && y_origen==200){ //S4

                        path.arcTo(ovalo_principal,192,66 ,true);
                        canvas.drawPath(path, pincel);
                        //                          canvas.drawTextOnPath(text, path, 50, 20, pincel);
                    }

                    if (x_origen==160 && y_origen==200){//S2

                        path.arcTo(ovalo_pequeño_superior,80,-160 ,true);
                        canvas.drawPath(path, pincel);
                        //                          canvas.drawTextOnPath(text, path, 50, 20, pincel);
                    }

                    if (x_origen==160 && y_origen==300){//S3

                        path.arcTo(ovalo_izquierda,38,-76 ,true);
                        canvas.drawPath(path, pincel);
                        //                          canvas.drawTextOnPath(text, path, 50, 20, pincel);
                    }
                    //                  }
                    contador=0;


                }

                if ((x>=x_S1-radio && x<=x_S1+radio) && (y>=y_S1-radio && y<=y_S1+radio)){//S1


                    x_destino=x_S1;
                    y_destino=y_S1;


                    if (x_origen==160 && y_origen==100){ //S0

                        path.arcTo(ovalo_superior_derecha,102,66,true);
                        canvas.drawPath(path, pincel);
                        //                          canvas.drawTextOnPath(text, path, 50, 20, pincel);
                    }

                    if (x_origen==60 && y_origen==200){ //S4

                        path.arcTo(ovalo_superior,127,-74,true);
                        canvas.drawPath(path, pincel);
                        //                          canvas.drawTextOnPath(text, path, 50, 20, pincel);
                    }

                    if (x_origen==160 && y_origen==200){//S2

                        path.arcTo(ovalo_pequeño_derecha,12,166 ,true);
                        canvas.drawPath(path, pincel);
                        //                          canvas.drawTextOnPath(text, path, 50, 20, pincel);
                    }

                    if (x_origen==160 && y_origen==300){//S3

                        path.arcTo(ovalo_principal,12,66 ,true);
                        canvas.drawPath(path, pincel);
                        //                          canvas.drawTextOnPath(text, path, 50, 20, pincel);
                    }
                    //                  }
                    contador=0;
                }

                if ((x>=x_S2-radio && x<=x_S2+radio) && (y>=y_S2-radio && y<=y_S2+radio)){//S2


                    x_destino=x_S2;
                    y_destino=y_S2;


                    if (x_origen==160 && y_origen==100){ //S0

                        path.arcTo(ovalo_pequeño_superior,102,156,true);
                        canvas.drawPath(path, pincel);
                        //                          canvas.drawTextOnPath(text, path, 50, 20, pincel);
                    }

                    if (x_origen==60 && y_origen==200){ //S4

                        path.arcTo(ovalo_pequeño_izquierda,12,166,true);
                        canvas.drawPath(path, pincel);
                        //                          canvas.drawTextOnPath(text, path, 50, 20, pincel);
                    }

                    if (x_origen==260 && y_origen==200){//S1

                        path.arcTo(ovalo_pequeño_derecha,-12,-166,true);
                        canvas.drawPath(path, pincel);
                        //                          canvas.drawTextOnPath(text, path, 50, 20, pincel);
                    }

                    if (x_origen==160 && y_origen==300){//S3

                        path.arcTo(ovalo_pequeño_inferior,102,156,true);
                        canvas.drawPath(path, pincel);
                        //                          canvas.drawTextOnPath(text, path, 50, 20, pincel);
                    }

                    //                  }
                    contador=0;
                }

                if ((x>=x_S3-radio && x<=x_S3+radio) && (y>=y_S3-radio && y<=y_S3+radio)){//S3


                    x_destino=x_S3;
                    y_destino=y_S3;

                    if (x_origen==160 && y_origen==100){ //S0

                        path.arcTo(ovalo_derecha,142,76,true);
                        canvas.drawPath(path, pincel);
                        //                          canvas.drawTextOnPath(text, path, 50, 20, pincel);
                    }

                    if (x_origen==60 && y_origen==200){ //S4

                        path.arcTo(ovalo_principal,102,76,true);
                        canvas.drawPath(path, pincel);
                        //                          canvas.drawTextOnPath(text, path, 50, 20, pincel);
                    }

                    if (x_origen==260 && y_origen==200){//S1

                        path.arcTo(ovalo_inferior_derecha,192,66,true);
                        canvas.drawPath(path, pincel);
                        //                          canvas.drawTextOnPath(text, path, 50, 20, pincel);
                    }

                    if (x_origen==160 && y_origen==200){//S2

                        path.arcTo(ovalo_pequeño_inferior,78,-156,true);
                        canvas.drawPath(path, pincel);
                        //                          canvas.drawTextOnPath(text, path, 50, 20, pincel);
                    }
                    //                  }
                    contador=0;
                }


                if ((x>=x_S4-radio && x<=x_S4+radio) && (y>=y_S4-radio && y<=y_S4+radio)){//S4


                    x_destino=x_S4;
                    y_destino=y_S4;


                    if (x_origen==160 && y_origen==100){ //S0

                        path.arcTo(ovalo_superior_izquierda,12,66,true);
                        canvas.drawPath(path, pincel);
                        //                          canvas.drawTextOnPath(text, path, 50, 20, pincel);
                    }

                    if (x_origen==160 && y_origen==300){ //S3

                        path.arcTo(ovalo_inferior_izquierda,-12,-66,true);
                        canvas.drawPath(path, pincel);
                        //                          canvas.drawTextOnPath(text, path, 50, 20, pincel);
                    }

                    if (x_origen==260 && y_origen==200){//S1

                        path.arcTo(ovalo_inferior,233,74,true);
                        canvas.drawPath(path, pincel);
                        //                          canvas.drawTextOnPath(text, path, 50, 20, pincel);
                    }

                    if (x_origen==160 && y_origen==200){//S2

                        path.arcTo(ovalo_pequeño_izquierda,192,156,true);
                        canvas.drawPath(path, pincel);
                        //                          canvas.drawTextOnPath(text, path, 50, 20, pincel);
                    }

                    //                  }
                    contador=0;
                }
            }

        }

        //Método que escucha si pulsamos la pantalla

        public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent e){

            //Obtenemos coordenadas de donde pulsamos
            x=e.getX();
            y=e.getY();

            //Si pulsamos cualquiera de los círculos

            if ((x>=x_S0-radio && x<=x_S0+radio) && (y>=y_S0-radio && y<=y_S0+radio)){ //S0

                if (e.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
                    accion="S0"; //señal para colorear de rojo el circulo
                }

                if (e.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
                    contador=contador+1; //contador de que hemos pulsado el primer círculo
                    if (contador==1){ //si pulsamos el primer círculo, guardamos las coordenadas de ese círculo como origen
                        x_origen=x_S0;
                        y_origen=y_S0;
                    }
                }
            }

            if ((x>=x_S1-radio && x<=x_S1+radio) && (y>=y_S1-radio && y<=y_S1+radio)){//S1

                if (e.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
                    accion="S1";
                }

                if (e.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
                    contador=contador+1;
                    if (contador==1){
                        x_origen=x_S1;
                        y_origen=y_S1;
                    }
                }
            }

            if ((x>=x_S2-radio && x<=x_S2+radio) && (y>=y_S2-radio && y<=y_S2+radio)){//S2

                if (e.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
                    accion="S2";
                }

                if (e.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
                    contador=contador+1;
                    if (contador==1){
                        x_origen=x_S2;
                        y_origen=y_S2;
                    }
                }
            }

            if ((x>=x_S3-radio && x<=x_S3+radio) && (y>=y_S3-radio && y<=y_S3+radio)){//S3

                if (e.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
                    accion="S3";
                }

                if (e.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
                    contador=contador+1;
                    if (contador==1){
                        x_origen=x_S3;
                        y_origen=y_S3;
                    }
                }
            }

            if ((x>=x_S4-radio && x<=x_S4+radio) && (y>=y_S4-radio && y<=y_S4+radio)){//S4

                if (e.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
                    accion="S4";
                }

                if (e.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
                    contador=contador+1;
                    if (contador==1){
                        x_origen=x_S4;
                        y_origen=y_S4;
                    }
                }
            }

            invalidate();

            return true;

        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Where did you get this code?

Comment: First of all, don't extend View, extend ViewGroup if you want your View to contain other groups.

Comment: Or else use a layout file and have the diagrama be just one element in the layout.   (Probably a better approach)

Comment: I have written this code.

"Or else use a layout file and have the diagrama be just one element in the layout. (Probably a better approach) – Dale Wilson"

If you send me a mail with an example of what you say, I would appreciate. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Don't extend view. Set up your entire layout how you want it to be, then take out the part that should be added and put it into a new XML in the "layouts" folder.

```
RelativeLayout parent= (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.item);
View element = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.element, parent);
```

Remember to change RelativeLayout to whatever kind of layout you have and to change the IDs.

Comment: If you please send to me the code (complete) with a spinner button added, i would appreciate. Thank you

Comment: Uhh, that is the code. Just copy-paste your spinner into an xml file in the "layouts" folder and run this code.

Answer (score 0):

I have created and xml (called "activity_main") with two spinners

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

After, I have finded one of this spinners inside onCreate

```
RelativeLayout parent= (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
```

And then, where I have to write this code?

```
getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.activity_main, parent);
```

Thank you Circuit Smasher